# Kotlin - Using Subtract and Intersect without mapping and using Find

Tags: android, database, kotlin, collections

Take the following code below in the function. I have a data class of `titleDto` as a list and a list of existing `titleIds`. I use the subtract and intersect methods to find what data is unique and common.

The purpose of this function and question is to find the titles which need added, deleted or updated in my database based on if the ids currently exist in the database or not compared with the titlesDto list.

The approach below feels inefficient. I have to map my list of `titlesDto` to their ids to do the subtract and intersect comparison then I have to use the find function to get the remaining titleDto data again. Is there a more efficient way to do this and combine the logic? Thanks in advance.

```
data class TitleDto(
    val titleId: Int,
    val title: String
    ...
)    

private fun modifyTitlesInDatabase(
    titlesListDto: List<TitleDto>,
    existingTitleIds: List<Int>,
): DatabaseModificationSummary {
    // Make sure both lists dont have any duplicates by converting to sets
    val jsonTitlesSet = titlesListDto.map { it.titleId }.toSet()
    val existingTitlesSet = existingTitleIds.toSet()

    val titleIdsToBeInserted = jsonTitlesSet.subtract(existingTitlesSet).distinct()
    val titleIdsToBeDeleted = existingTitleIds.subtract(jsonTitlesSet).distinct()
    val titleIdsThatCouldBeUpdated = jsonTitlesSet.intersect(existingTitlesSet)

    titleIdsToBeInserted.forEach { titleToBeInsertedId ->
        titlesListDto.find { it.titleId == titleToBeInsertedId }?.let { title ->
            titlesCache.insertTitle(title = title)
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Why won't consider mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `TitleDto` so that it take into account only `titleId`. Thus, you can operate with two `Set<TitleDto>` without having to map it to `Set<Int>`.

But be careful in case it may break some other logic where `TitleDto` is involved.

Comment: Don't need to do that since data classes override `equals` and `hashCode` automatically, and hashcode for dtos with different ids will be different anyways

Comment: @Steyrix yes, but difference in `title` then would have led to inequality, however it looks like that in the context of operations with collections only `titleId` is taken into account. So, instead of mapping to the `Set<Int>` and then finding the right `TitleDto`, it might be easier make operations with `Set<TitleDto>` work the same way as with `Set<Int>`, but of course it depends on the rest of the logic with `TitleDto`

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you consider using another data structure to simplify the approach? I am not sure about DB framework you use, but to me it seems like `HashMap` collection is the way to go.

```
val dataMap: HashMap<Int, TitleDto> = ... // You need to convert existing DB data to hashmap

titlesListDto.forEach {
    if(dataMap.containsKey(it.titleId)) {
        if (dataMap!!.[it.titleId] == it) {
            // exists the same, so don't need to update or insert
        } else {
            dataMap[it.titleId] = it
            // exists, but data is different, update map and DB
        }
    } else {
        dataMap[it.titleId] = it
        // doesn't exist, so should be inserted to map and to DB
        titlesCache.insertTitle(title = it.title)
    }
}
```

For deletion you can use something like this (a little bit hacky though)

```
dataMap.entries.removeIf { entry ->
    if(!titleListDto.contains(entry.value)) {
        // delete from DB
        true
    }
    false
}
```

Technically it should take N time complexity in case when there are no collisions by hash codes.